# robots "INDEX,FOLLOW" vs "ALL" is there any difference?

Tags: google, search-engines, yahoo, seo

Hey folks,
Is there *any* if so, *what* is the difference between these two?
In order to allow everything a search engines wishes for

`<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="index, follow">`

`<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="all"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They both have one thing in common: they do nothing. By default search engines and robots will crawl and index everything which makes those tags redundant and unnecessary. The meta robots tag is to be used when you want to **prevent** content from being crawled and or indexed.

Answer (score 10):

"all" isn't a valid attribute.

Valid values for the attribute are: "INDEX", "NOINDEX", "FOLLOW", "NOFOLLOW".

"INDEX,FOLLOW" is the default behaviour so neither examples will make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

some of the meta tags I have seen:

"INDEX, FOLLOW" 
"INDEX, NOFOLLOW" 
"NOINDEX, FOLLOW" 
"NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"

With the first one : Index,follow you are allowing the spider to search your page and update in their search engine.